# Bind USB Disk devices connected to a USB hub to certain device names based on USB Hub Port connected to

Tags: ubuntu, udev, usb-drive

This is going to sound sorta vague, but I have an ANKER USB 3.0 hub.  I want to be able to connect multiple USB disks to here, however I want the Linux system to be able to assign the device name (i.e. `/dev/sdX`) based on the USB port that the device is connected to on the hub.  I have 9 data enabled ports, so port 1 would get `/dev/sdb`, port 2 would get `/dev/sdc`, etc.  I have no other disks on this computer, so I don't see a need to worry about device name collisions, but I would like to make such a binding happen.

Is this at all possible, and if it is, how would I structure a set of `udev` rules to do this?  Using Ubuntu 16.04, but would like it to work in modern Debian (stable or later) as well.

Comment: Does it have to be /dev/sdX? Would /dev/disk/by-path do what you want?

Comment: @icarus If we could define what `by-path` would be, so that each is unique per USB port, then that'd work.

Comment: `by-path` is a directory, which contains filenames like `pci-0000:00:12.2-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0` which tell you the motherboard location, and then the usb location.

Comment: And in case it's unclear, `by-path` is already automatically populated with symlinks by standard udev rules. No need to write new ones for that.